# CSS - transition width inside a parent with width 100% - only working in one direction?

Tags: css, css-transitions

I have this CSS transition set up to smoothly hide and show a search bar:

https://codepen.io/Carces/pen/PoXPKzd

The transition works in isolation, and it always works when the bar goes from hidden to shown. However, when it goes from shown to hidden, there's no transition - it happens instantly.

The culprit seems to be the 'width: 100%' setting on the nav element - when that's removed, it works fine. I can see how a conflict could potentially arise here, but not sure I fully understand what's happening or why.

I do need to the nav bar to cover the full width of the screen, and to remain in something like the current layout, with the two elements at opposite ends, but other than I'm open to any suggestions.

Relevant CSS from the CodePen:

```
:root {
  --page-background: #f2f2f2;
  --nav-background: #ffffff;
  --footer-background: #ad9463;
  --button: #8fbfdd;
  --button-text: #212e40;
  --button-dark: #212e40;
  --text-light: #ffffff;
  --text-dark: #000000;
}

nav {
  background-color: var(--nav-background);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 50;
  padding: 20px 150px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#search-bar {
  transition: width 0.5s;
}

.bar-shown {
  width: 20rem;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px var(--button-dark) solid;
}

.bar-hidden {
  border: none;
  width: 0;
}
```

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here, **within your question**, and [not a link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254430/162698) to any other site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will smoothly show and hide the search bar, you can test [here](https://jsfiddle.net/e4msrzLt/1/)

I've also added opacity to the search bar, it fades in nicely, also it hides the glitched border when adding class `.bar-hidden`

also I've added `outline: none` to remove the focus selection of the search-bar, its now clean and smooth

```css
#search-bar {
  width: 0; /* Set the initial width */
  transition: width 0.5s, opacity 0.5s;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px var(--button-dark) solid;
  outline:none;
}

.bar-shown {
  width: 20rem !important;
  opacity:1;
}

.bar-hidden {
  width: 0 !important;
  opacity:0;
}
```

your initial issue was caused by having
`border-bottom`
in the `.bar-shown` css class